# launchimage : trigger.io forge default launchimage is displayed before mine

Tags: trigger.io

I use the latest version of trigger.io forge (latest stable version of forge -2.5.1 - and of all modules like launchimage 2.12), but when i launch app on ios 9 or 10, i can see 2 or 3 seconds, the default "Trigger.io Forge" splash screen before mine.

Is it a new "commercial" displayed recently ? Or is it a bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 10 Apple caches the launchimage the first time the app is launched. Unfortunately there is a bug with the implementation in that it does not pick up on subsequent changes to the launchimage!

The workaround is as follows:

- Uninstall your app from the device.
- Reboot your device. (Very important, the cache won't get cleared if you just delete the app)
- Reinstall the app with the new launch image.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfect. This is, as you said, a problem on Apple side that should clear the cache when appropriate.